# How do I put a .csv file correctly into an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

So I'd like to make a basic login/register page. I got a CSV file which roughly looks like this:

```
a, b      
r,d 
login, pass
```

I am already able to correctly add new combinations to the file. But if I want to put the CSV into an array so that I can check if the username/password combination is true, I only get the first row in the array, so [0] = "a" and [1] = "b". There are similar questions on this site on how to put a csv into an array, but with every solution this problem comes up. How do I get the other elements in the array, too?

Edit: as suggested, the code I used:

```
$database = fopen("database.csv", "r");
                $data = fgetcsv($database, 1000, ",");
                print_r($data);
```

This returns: `Array ( [0] => q [1] => w )`

Exact data:

```
q,w
g,h
o,p
t,y
c,d
o,p
o,p
a,b
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php   . use the example of the link and check

Comment: Show us what code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) that `fgetcsv` returns just one line from the file pointer, and `NULL` or `FALSE` if it was unable to get another line.

You should put your code in a while loop to get all of the CSV rows.

```
$credentials = array();
$database = fopen("database.csv", "r");
while (is_array($data = fgetcsv($database, 1000, ','))) {
    $credentials[] = $data;
}
fclose($database);

var_dump($credentials); // This contains all of the credentials.
```